# JDBC update database

Tags: mysql, jdbc, sql-update, executequery

i have a form and onClick listener i want to update some data on my database exception says that i have a syntax error but when i execute query at mysql console it works here is my code all variables are checked

```
String temp =  itemList.getModel().getElementAt(itemList.getSelectedIndex()).toString();
PreparedStatement pt = supplies.con.prepareStatement("update prods set pquant = pquant + ? where pname = ?");
pt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(empsalary.getText()));
pt.setString(2, temp);
supplies.pst.executeQuery(temp);
```

#### Error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DVD Verdatim' at line 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3206)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:1232)
at buy$1.actionPerformed(buy.java:62)
```

Comment: Can you show the error message please?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DVD Verdatim' at line 1
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3277)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3206)

Comment: include the error message in your question please!

Comment: Yeah I know what exactly is happening, your SQL statement is no good..

Comment: Please run your sql statement in DB before using with Java code.

Comment: my statement runs in DB where why my statement its not good ?

Comment: Can you add `System.out.println(pt.toString());` before the `executeQuery` statement and provide the actual query that throws the error?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement@55b5ff11: update prods set pquant = pquant + 21 where pname = 'DVD Verdatim'

Comment: i try to run update query without preparedStatement its ok but it dont update my DB when i try to delete a row it works

Comment: @Seekarakos, I have updated my answer. Do you have a variable for pquant and pname?

Comment: yes now i run "update prods set pquant = pquant + 30 where pname = 'DVD Verdatim'" and it worked but again i cant updated with preparedStatement

Comment: I fount my error i declare a variable pt and i execute the query from the statement that is empty pst i change to pt.executeUpdate(); and its ok now

Comment: I fount my error i declare a variable pt and i execute the query from the statement that is empty pst i change to pt.executeUpdate(); and its ok now

Comment: A very basic error didn't catch anyone's eyes :(

Comment: sorry for wasting your time for my mistake

Comment: There is no need for you to apologize.  I was talking about all of us not finding that error in the code :)

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler mentioned, there is indeed a Syntax error in your SQL query. Try:

```
String temp =  itemList.getModel().getElementAt(itemList.getSelectedIndex()).toString();
PreparedStatement pt = supplies.con.prepareStatement("update prods set pquant = @0 + 21" + "'variableForPquant'" "where pname = @1" + "'variableForPname'");
pt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(empsalary.getText()));
pt.setString(2, temp);
supplies.pst.executeQuery(temp);
```

You need to use quotes when you are using variables in your SQL query. I believe it is either

`"'variableName'"` or `'"variableName'"`

Comment: with "?" and pst.setString java add single quotes

Comment: Generally the ? will be the variable name you set the input for your query. But from what I can see in your code, it looks like the quotes are not there for your query and that is probably what the compilers complaining about.

Comment: I fount my error i declare a variable pt and i execute the query from the statement that is empty pst i change to pt.executeUpdate(); and its ok now

Answer (score 0):

I found my error i declare a variable pt and i execute the query from the statement that is empty pst i change to pt.executeUpdate(); and its ok now